# catch coordinate from GPS in c# windows forms

Tags: c#

i am running the gmap.net in c# windows form project، i have a gps devise that connected to my pc via RS232,i want to catch my location coordinate via gps, but dont know how to do it?
best regards.

Comment: You need to get NMEA string from your GPS and then parse it, [SharpGPS](http://sharpgps.codeplex.com/) could be a starting point. Also [this code project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23135/Mapping-with-a-GPS-and-C) could provide you some starting point.